# How do I determine the initial condition from differential equations?

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble with determining the initial  condition of this problem:

Suppose people start smoking in a room of volume 60 $m^3$, thereby introducing air containing 5% carbon monoxide at a rate of 0.002 $m^3$/min into the room. Assume that the smoky air mixes immediately and uniformly with the rest of the air, and that this mixture leaves the room at the same rate as the smoky air enters. Assume that there is no carbon monoxide in the room initially.

I have attempted the question and managed to get the differential equation:

$dy\over dx$$+$$10x\over 20000-5t $=$5$

I then got x(t) = $(20 000-5t)^2 + C (20 000 - 5t)^2$

I need to solve for C now but I don't know how to determine the initial condition.

Hoping I could get some help with this. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Look at the last sentence of your second paragraph.

Comment: Hmmm since they said assume there is no carbon monoxide in the room initially, would the initial condition then be x(0) = 0?

Comment: If $x$ represents the amount of carbon monoxide in the room, yes!

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that the smoking starts at $t=0$, then let $x(0)=0$ into $ x(t)=(20 000-5t)^2 + C (20 000 - 5t)^2$  and find your C.

Comment: yup I plugged x(0) = 0 into the equation but I'm still not getting the answer reflected in my problem booklet. The answer shows 5(4000-t)^2 - 1/1600 (4000-t)^2. I managed to get the first part of the answer correct but I'm getting - 1/4000 instead of -1/1600

Comment: Then you need to check your differential equation again.